# Sentence embedding using T5

Tags: python, nlp, pytorch, word-embedding

I would like to use state-of-the-art LM T5 to get sentence embedding vector.
I found this repository https://github.com/UKPLab/sentence-transformers
As I know, in BERT I should take the first token as [CLS] token, and it will be the sentence embedding.
In this repository I see the same behaviour on T5 model:

```
cls_tokens = output_tokens[:, 0, :]  # CLS token is first token
```

Does this behaviour correct? I have taken encoder from T5 and encoded two phrases with it:

```
"I live in the kindergarden"
"Yes, I live in the kindergarden"
```

The cosine similarity between them was only "0.2420".

I just need to understand how sentence embedding works - should I train network to find similarity to reach correct results? Or I it is enough of base pretrained language model?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to obtain the sentence embedding from the T5, you need to take the take the `last_hidden_state` from the T5 encoder output:

```
model.encoder(input_ids=s, attention_mask=attn, return_dict=True)
pooled_sentence = output.last_hidden_state # shape is [batch_size, seq_len, hidden_size]
# pooled_sentence will represent the embeddings for each word in the sentence
# you need to sum/average the pooled_sentence
pooled_sentence = torch.mean(pooled_sentence, dim=1)
```

You have now a sentence embeddings from T5

Comment: Also, note that you have to ignore the mask when doing the mean: `(output.last_hidden_state * attn.unsqueeze(-1)).sum(dim=-2) / attn.sum(dim=-1)`

Comment: To back up this idea further, in [Sentence-T5](https://arxiv.org/abs/2108.08877) they show that the mean token embedding is a great choice for T5.